# using alert in elasticsearch with java API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data written into Elasticsearch in near real time and i want to be alerted when that data matches certain patterns, ElastAlert is the tool for doing this. However i want to use alert with java API, it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

To implement Alert when data match specific queries you should use the Percolator.

It allows you to store some queries and you can either alert or tag the document as you please.

SEE : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html